# How to avoid recycling while trying to replace values from a vector in a dataframe column

Tags: r, replace, recycle

This question arose, while working on this question [Replace list names if they exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74320274/replace-list-names-if-they-exist)

**I have this manipulated iris dataset with two vectors:**

```
new_name <- c("new_setoas", "new_virginica")
to_select <- c("setosa", "virginica")
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species))

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>     
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    
2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa    
3          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
4          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
5          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 virginica 
6          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
```

I would like to replace values in Species selected from a vector (`to_select`) with values from another vector (`new_name`)

**When I do:**

```
new_name <- c("new_setoas", "new_virginica")
to_select <- c("setosa", "virginica")
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>% 
  mutate(Species = ifelse(Species %in% to_select, new_name, Species))

# I get:

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species      
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>        
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 new_setoas   
2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 **new_virginica** # should be new_setoas
3          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor   
4          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor   
5          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 **new_setoas** # should be new_virginica   
6          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 new_virginica
```

While I know this is happening because of **recycling**. I don't know how to avoid this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `recode` - instead of grouping and then modifying the group column afterwards, it can be done at the `group_by` step itself

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species =  recode(as.character(Species),
     !!!setNames(new_name, to_select))) %>% 
  slice(1:2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species      
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>        
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 new_setoas   
2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 new_setoas   
3          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor   
4          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor   
5          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 new_virginica
6          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 new_virginica
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `match` is more complicated than [akrun's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74321300/8245406) but here it goes.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

new_name <- c("new_setoas", "new_virginica")
to_select <- c("setosa", "virginica")

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>% 
  mutate(i_new = match(Species, to_select)) %>%
  mutate(Species = ifelse(is.na(i_new), Species, new_name[i_new])) %>%
  select(-i_new)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species      
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>        
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 new_setoas   
#> 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 new_setoas   
#> 3          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor   
#> 4          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor   
#> 5          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 new_virginica
#> 6          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 new_virginica
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>